# Grails spock unit test for redirect and render

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a following function to be unit tested. But I am stuck on how to exactly test it. Also is it necessary to unit test these sorts of functions? I am using Grails 2.5.1 and spock 0.7.Please suggest.

```
    def allGeneralNotes() {
    def ben = Beneficiary.findById(params.id)
    if(!ben){
        redirect(controller: 'dashboard',action: 'index')
    }

    def generalNotes = Note.findAllByBeneficiaryAndTypeAndIsDeleted(Beneficiary.findById(params.id), NoteType.GENERAL,false).sort { it.dateCreated }.reverse()
    def userNames =  noteService.getUserName(generalNotes);
    render view: 'generalNotes', model: [id: params.id, generalNotes: generalNotes, userNames:userNames]
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to testing, but your controller action is going to be a problem because you are not returning after calling `redirect` so control is going to flow through to the call to `render` after calling `redirect`.  You should either `return` after `redirect`, or reorganize your `if{...}` logic so everything below the `redirect` is in an `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to assume the names for a number of facets but hopefully the following will get you going in the right direction.
One thing to note is that you call `Beneficiary.findById(params.id)` twice in your controller method, you could just pass `ben` into `findAllByBeneficiaryAndTypeAndIsDeleted`.

You may have to add parameters to the new objects returned by the mocked methods below too.

```
@TestFor( BeneficiaryController )
@Mock( [ Beneficiary, Note ] )
class BeneficiaryControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def noteService = Mock( NoteService )

    void setup() {
        controller.noteService = noteService
    }

    void "test allGeneralNotes no beneficiary" () {
        when:
            controller.allGeneralNotes()
        then:
            response.redirectedUrl == '/dashboard/index'
    }

    void "test allGeneralNotes beneficiary found" () {
        given:
            Beneficiary.metaClass.static.findById{ a -> new Beneficiary()}
            Note.findAllByBeneficiaryAndTypeAndIsDeleted = { a, b -> [new Note(dateCreated: new Date()), new Note(dateCreated: new Date())]}
        when:
            controller.allGeneralNotes()
        then:
            1 * noteService.getUserName( _ ) >> 'whatever username is'
            view == '/generalNotes'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, it helped me sort out exactly what i was looking for.  :)